# Unable to parse json response in Sencha application

Tags: javascript, html, json, sencha-touch-2

I want to learn how to develop mobile application. So I started using Sencha framework.

I downloaded the sample application from [here](http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/creating-a-simple-list-in-sencha-touch-2-0/). When I run from localhost application, I don't see the list view.

I don't modified the code. Just copy folder and run in browser from localhost...

I expected like from: http://jbk404.site50.net/sencha/datahandling/

What I received (a warning in Chrome): [large picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8cE6.png)

[image]

and the head structure of index.html file:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Sample test</title>
    <link href="resources/css/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="sencha-touch-all-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Does the file data/contacts.json exist in your app ?

Comment: Yes, it exists otherwise will throw 404... Can you try please yourself locally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the example is using an older version of sencha touch. If you change the JSON file to this this structure it will probably work:

```
[ {
    "firstName": "Pearlie",
    "lastName": "White",
    "contactno": "011-9865460",
    "address": "365-Andrews Street, CA"
}]
```

Hope it works for you, made a fiddle file just copy the code in to a new fiddle and it will work. http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/6aE31/

Greets